# How to plot a pandas groupby subset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have grouped two variables

```
groups = df.groupby(['CLUSTER_ID','DATE']).count()
```

the grouped data shows as below

```
CLUSTER_ID  DATE
   1        2018-01-07
            2018-01-12
            2018-01-15
            2018-01-27
  2         2018-01-02
            2018-01-09
            2018-01-11
            2018-01-28
```

when I subset with for example 'CLUSTER_ID'=1 and 'DATE'=2018-09 I get

```
DATE
2018-09-07
2018-09-13
2018-09-22
2018-09-23
2018-09-26
2018-09-29
```

I want a more efficient way to subset the group, maybe by defining a function or something. I also want to be able to plot the subset, I tried with

```
groups.loc[1]['2018,jan'].plot()
```

and

```
plt.plot(groups.loc[1]['2018,jan'])
```

but it does not work. please any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: What is `print (df.head())` ?

Comment: `DATE                      CLUSTER_ID`
`0      2018-06-07      1`
`1         2018-06-07      2`
`2         2018-06-07      4`
`3         2018-06-07      1`
`4         2018-06-07      3`